# Magento Terms & Conditions max character limit

Tags: magento, character, limit, checkout, maxlength

I have a problem here that even after hours of searching with my friend Google, I'm still getting no results...

My Terms & Conditions are larger then the max character set of the Magento section for it.

Then I would like to know if one of you could please help me to locate the file and the line to edit to make the max character set biger and letting me put all my Terms & Condition without problem.

Thank you very much in advance for your time.

sincerely,

Nicolas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The T&C content is stored in the `checkout_agreement` table in a field named `content`

This field is assigned the datatype `text` and has a maximum length of around 64kB with actual content depending on how many bytes your UTF-8 encoded text uses.

You would need to change the datatype to `longtext` which has a maximum length of 16MB.

Testing this will be necessary to make sure no validation limits have been imposed on the entry template.

Comment: Thanks to you both for these quick answers! I found it in my phpmyadmin but as I'm not very used to work with SQL table and stuff it would be really helpful if one of you could show to me what syntax do I need to use to make these changes? My database is already exported so if I do any mystake everything should be fine after importing it over again.

Answer (score 1):

You can modify the table structure of table `checkout_agreement` by changing the data type of `content` field from `TEXT` to `LONGTEXT` to allow for more characters.

Comment: Thank you for your fast answer! You are right there is the place to do it! :)